# How to make a Ticket Workflow when you have different environments?

Tags: workflow, jira, environments

I have different environments (2, 3 or even 4) depending on the task that will be done.

I have a few status, like: in progress, resolved.

When some task is verified in a lower environment, it needs to be verified in then next (upper) environment. I think about two ways to handle this on Jira:

1) Setting the workflow with both the status of the ticket, and the environment, in a way that when you approve a ticket, it automatically changes to the next environment in the proper status. Example:

You had the ticket in the status Resolved-DEV, and it changes to In Progress-PreProd. Assuming that PreProd is the next environment. And so on...

My concern is that this approach is too rigid and not necessary.

2) Having a basic workflow that does NOT include the environment in it, and including the environment that represents the actual status in a dropdown menu inside the ticket. Example:

You have a ticket on Resolved status, and the dropdown reads: DEV. You test it, you approve it, so it goes to the next environment. The status changes to In progress, and you have to manually change the environment dropdown to PreProd. Or, the dropdown environment can be changed automatically with a post-function (which can be configured if you use Jira).

My concern is that this approach is too flexible, and requires more concentration. But I don't see a problem using it.

What do you think is the best approach? did you think about a different way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If every ticket have to solve the different environments, it should be covered by your workflow, because it is you workflow ;)

Also inside a more fancy workflow you can handle the situation when a ticket need to "drop-down" to a lower env because of some tests are failing...